# Dynamically updating a table row in HTA (VBS)

Tags: html, vba, vbscript, hta

After researching I can see that to dynamically update a table within a HTA, I need to add the `tbody` element. I can also see that then I need to use the `appendchild` function to add the necessary data / rows to the table.

I've done this and am trying to loop through an array `ArrLogs` using the code below

```
Dim i
i = 1
Set table = document.getElementById("maintable") 
Set tbody = document.createElement("tbody") 
table.appendChild(tbody) 
Set trow = document.createElement("tr") 
Set tcol = document.createElement("td") 

ArrLogs = ReadLogs(computerasset.value)

Do Until i = UBound(ArrLogs)
       tcol.innerHTML = ArrLogs(i) 
       trow.appendChild(tcol) 
       tbody.appendChild(trow)
       table.appendChild(tbody)  
       i = i+1
Loop
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm only seeing the last value of my array appended to the table, almost as if I'm missing a command to save the append and it's overwriting the row as it runs through?

I'm very concious that this isn't tidy, or the correct way to loop through an array (should use `for i = 1 to UBound(ArrLogs)` etc) - I was testing different ways of doing things in case I was making an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trow.appendChild(tcol)` does not *copy* `tcol` to the row; it inserts a *reference* to it, meaning that you only ever have *one* `tcol` that you constantly overwrite, E.g. the code below would show B not A

```
Set p = document.createElement("p") 
p.innerHTML = "A"
document.body.appendChild(p)
p.innerHTML = "B"
```

To fix this create new elements inside your loop:

```
Dim i: i = 0

Set tbody = document.createElement("tbody") 

ArrLogs = ReadLogs(computerasset.value)

for i = lbound(ArrLogs) to ubound(ArrLogs)
    Set trow = document.createElement("tr") 
    Set tcol = document.createElement("td") 

    tcol.innerHTML = ArrLogs(i) 
    trow.appendChild(tcol)
    tbody.appendChild(trow)
Next

document.getElementById("maintable").appendChild(tbody)
```

Comment: Just tested, and that has done exactly what I'm looking for. I can now see how I was inserting a reference which would be overwritten, however I don't understand why I didn't have `i` copies of it written to the table?